# How do you allow a site member to Change thier login (which is thier email) on a Wix member site?

Tags: velo

I'm working on a Wix site which has their membership options (login, member area, profile, etc). Wix forces the users to log in with their email address and manages the passwords for me, so if a customer forgets their password, they can click "forgot" and reset it.

My question is how can I allow site members to change their login (which is their email they signed up with)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Corvid does not provide that functionality.